# Trying to pull hashtags from sentence, only works if sentence is one word.

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use PHP to grab the hashtags from captions on an xml page and then using the words minus the hashtags as ids for list items. What I've got so far only will work if the caption only includes the hashtag. If there's more to the sentence it won't return anything. What do I need to do to make it work correctly?

```
preg_match_all('#<title>\#(\w+)</title>#Us', $item, $temp );
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample text, and what your desired result is?

Comment: Sure, @JonathanSampson I'd like to go through an xml entity like this- `<title>Blurry pencil is blurry. #coolthings</title>` and turn the hashtag into something like `<li id="coolthings">` It's working, but only if there's only a hashtag in the `<title>` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
preg_match_all('~<title>(?:[^<#]*\s)?#(\w+)[^<]*</title>~s', $item, $temp);
```

It allows anything besides `<` or `#` between the `<title>` and the hashtag, provided the hashtag itself is preceded by whitespace; and it will allow anything besides `<` between the hashtag and the `</title>`.

Note that this will only match one hashtag per title. If you need to be able to get multiple hashtags from a single title, I recommend that you first use `preg_match_all` to get the titles, and then, for each title, use `preg_match_all` to get its hashtag(s), if any.

Comment: This is almost working, but it's only pulling the first letter of the hashtag word. I'll tinker with it, but I'm very new to regex.

Comment: @elkirkmo: Hmm, that's strange. Maybe try changing `(\w+)` to `((?>\w+))`, using http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.onlyonce.php? (That *shouldn't* make a difference here, but trying it might at least help narrow down the problem.)

Comment: Unfortunately, that does the same thing.

Comment: @elkirkmo: Oh, oops, duh, it's because of the `U` modifier flag, which makes the regex "ungreedy". Sorry for not noticing it before. You need to remove that. (I'll edit my answer accordingly.)